# Java : Error loading resources folder

Tags: java, classpath

I have four java files in package com.book.week. All the files are in a folder named java. I am running my program from this folder. The java folder is in main directory which has another folder named resources. Resources has .txt files.

When i run it using

```
java -cp /* com.book.week.Main
```

I get a file not found error. I want to run this from command line. How do i tell my program through classpath that where to find the resources folder ?

Comment: Your code and the exception stack trace would help better.

Comment: At some places in the output is says : Error - src/main/resources/abc.txt

Comment: I am sorry, but please provide the code and entire stack trace. The text you provided is very broad to investigate.

Comment: you work in eclipse/netbeans where? if you provide a picture would be helpfull....

Comment: if you have some static resource then theses should be in /src/main/resources/ ..... (maven,gradle), It is better to create jar with our classes and resources together.